# Cannot install on late 2006 intel imac

Tags: system-installation

I have a late 2006 intel imac running osx lion (10.75) off an external usb drive (the internal drive is dead). I have followed the instructions to create a bootable usb drive with etch but it is not recognized on startup. I then reverted to plan b as suggested in the mac installation instructions and burned the iso to a dvd. This was not recognized either. My computer does not have enough free resources to use a virtual machine. Note, I am not trying to dual boot. I want to erase my hard drive and replace osx with Elementary OS. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: See if it helps: https://mattgadient.com/2016/07/11/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/

Comment: Something more to help: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-boot-a-linux-live-usb-stick-on-your-mac/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to install Elementary os Loki as long as the 2006 MacBook runs a 64bits Mac OS. For Example I installed it using a dvd myself. if you have a dvd that you or someone burnt Elementary os loki or a usb with Elementary os loki. 
Put in the dvd/usb, turn off the macbook. Turn the macbook on, and hold the option key ... 'till you see a white screen. 
Start elementary Deskyop without installing
and play with the OS before you decide to install

Elementary os is fun on Macbook.